# longpolling odoo 11 does not show in the log

Tags: python, odoo, long-polling, odoo-11

My longpolling from a create function does not work, any help?
I try to get a `(channel,message)` sent and receive it on a .js file to update the content of a one-page app without reloading the page like 
[this](https://github.com/dbo-odoo/odoo-js-demo/tree/master/ticket_viewer)
in ticket.py:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import api, fields, models


class DemoTicket(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'pos.order'
    _description = 'Demo Ticket'

    name = fields.Char(required=True)
    description = fields.Text()

    @api.model
    def create_from_ui(self, orders):
        # Keep only new orders
        order_ids = super(DemoTicket, self).create_from_ui(orders)
        (channel, message) = ((self._cr.dbname, 'pos.order', order_ids[0]), ('new_ticket', order_ids[0]))
        self.env['bus.bus'].sendone(channel, message)
        # print(channel)
        # print(message)

    return order_ids
```

the `print(channel)` and `print(message)` actually show, but after the `create_from_ui`, in the log, there is not a longpolling.

I saw the use of this on the odoo experience 2017, modified the code a bit to adapt to my custom module,

Comment: Do you want to send a message from point of sale screen (client side ) to the backend (serverside) or vice verse?

Comment: I want to send a longpoll everytime a pos.order is created by the `create_from_gui` function of `pos.order`,

Comment: then the longpolling will be catched in a controller.js file and will fetch the new ticket from the database and refresh the ticket viewer one-page app without refreshing the window,